# how to prove that 1/x is distributed as an Birnbaum-Saunders

Tags: r

I have to show that if T ∼ BS(α, β) then 1/T∼ BS(α, 1/β)
How should I do it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Here the pdf  and the CDF of the Birnbaum-Saunders.
[image: pdf Birnbaum-Saunders]
[image]